# Multiple arrays and nested arrays with AngularFire

Tags: arrays, firebase, angularfire

Everything is nice when you have only one array.

```
var ref = new Firebase("...");
var sync = $firebase(ref);
var test =  sync.$asArray();
```

So I have an array in *test* on which I can operate with *$add, $save* and *$remove*.

But what if I want a second array? I've tried this:

```
var ref = new Firebase("...");
var sync = $firebase(ref);
var test =  sync.$asArray();
var test2 =  sync.$asArray();
```

But if I add something to *test2*, it goes to the same DB as the one *test* uses. Am I using it wrong? Do I need to create a new Firebase db for each array?

Is it possible to create a dynamic number of arrays?
Is it possible, to nest arrays into arrays? Example: a list of todo lists.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you call `$asArray` on the same `$firebase` sync twice, so naturally this leads to two references to the same array.

If you want two separate arrays, you'll need to set up a separate reference to the data for each of them:

```
var ref1 = new Firebase("https://yours.firebaseio.com/array1");
var ref2 = new Firebase("https://yours.firebaseio.com/array2");
var sync1 = $firebase(ref1);
var sync2 = $firebase(ref2);
var test =  sync1.$asArray();
var test2 =  sync2.$asArray();
```

Comment: WOW, thanks! I have tried it with a new instance, but I've used the same URL. Silly me. The nesting is still an issue 'tho. Of course, I can use a list, to store the URL-s of the sublists, but a simple `main.$add(sub)` would be much more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't an easy ride, but finally I found a simple way to do this. Check it out [here](https://frontendcorner.wordpress.com/2015/01/24/nested-arrays-in-angularfire/).